# How do I create a jump link to a paragraph item?

Tags: tokens, paragraphs

I'm trying to create a jump link to the paragraph item. This is what I tried

1. create a compact display of the page just printing out a title and short summary.
2. using the [advanced text formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_text_formatter) I created a link in this index

It takes me to the paragraph page. I figure that I can use a token in the advanced text formatter to create an anchor link from the compact display to the detailed display. Then I have to work out how to add the anchor to the detailed display.

- How do I create a link with the delta as the anchor e.g. /abc/test.html#1?
- How do i create the anchor on the detailed display?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Paragraphs Table of Contents](https://www.drupal.org/project/ptoc) module is good enough for what you describe.

From the project page

> If you have long pages on your site, then it helps visitors if you can provide in-page navigation, or a table of contents.
>
> If you build your long pages with the Paragraphs module, then you can use Paragraphs Table of Contents to provide the in-page navigation. There is one link in the table of contents (ToC) for each paragraph on the page.